# Jackson always serialize full object or always just serialize id

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using the annotation @JsonIdentityInfo to serialize / deserialize an object using it's id.

I implemented an ObjectIdResolver, that is working well.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id", resolver = EntityIdResolver.class, scope = MyClass.class)
public class MyClass{....}
```

I found the documentation of this annotation  [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html).

My problem is the statement: "In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full object and object identity, and other references to the object as reference values."

Now my Rest-Endpoint return something similar to

```
{
"itemList": [
    {
        "id": 70110,
        "myClass": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "itemName",
            "date": "2000-01-01"
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 70111,
        "myClass": 3,
    }
]
}
```

But this means, the the client has to deal with different data types. The client does know all the objects, so it does not matter if the serialization returns either allways the id only or the full object.

How do I prevent Jackson from using this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution (at least for my problem) quite quickly:
Adding

```
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
```

to MyClass will allways seralize as

```
"myClass":3
```

I found this [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/372)